# How to distinguish EC2-Classic and EC2-VPC instances in AWS?

Tags: amazon-ec2

It is said [in manual](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)

> After you launch an instance in EC2-Classic, you can't change its
>   security groups .... If you're using EC2-VPC, you must use security
>   groups created specifically for your VPC...

Okay, have an instance list in `Instances` section, how would I know are they `VPC` or `Classic`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you created your account after 2013-12-04, it supports EC2-VPC only.

You can select your instance from the EC2 dashboard and look at the property window below. If you find `VPC ID` and `Subnet ID` you are on EC2-VPC.

[image]